# Create a dynamic route param in Vue Router that removes spaces

Tags: javascript, vue.js, replace, vue-component, vue-router

I have a bunch of boxes in my app that route to a page where you can see all of the items that are in the box. As it stands my dynamic route in the index.js file looks like this:

```
{
  path: '/box/:idBox',
  name: 'ItemListByBox',
  component: ItemListByBox,
},
```

All of my `boxID`s (`idBox`) are all strings such as `Box 1`, `Box 2`, etc.

Everything works totally fine and routes you to the right page, but the page address at the top winds up looking like `http://localhost:8080/box/Box%202`

Is there a way to have the address look like `Box-2`?

Cheers!

Comment: That's the url encoding for a space.  Change the id string instead

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How do you mean when you say "change the id string"?

Comment: You're welcome.  Assuming you have a `<router-link>` to a destination `Box 1`, rename it `Box-1` instead.  Better yet, remove the word `Box` altogether so that it looks like:  `http://localhost:8080/box/2`

Comment: @shob So the trouble with that, is that this is data that is set by the user. They're allowed to name their boxes anything they wish, so I can't just call it Box-1. Do you think I would I need to write a function to take all entered strings and replace spaces with "-"?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like that would be necessary

Comment: Would do that in the index.js page then? I've been goofing around with that implimentation, but it seems that messing with a dynamic route is not going to work
{path: '`/box/:${idBox.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase}`',}

This just throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a computed to transform the user input (mentioned in comments) so that spaces are replaced with dashes.  You don't need to change your route configuration.

Imagine you have a data variable that gets modified by user input called `boxID` and may contain spaces.  Pass the computed as the route param like this:

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'ItemListByBox', params: { idBox: boxFormatted }}">
  CREATE BOX
</router-link>
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    boxID: 'Box 1'
  }),
  computed: {
    boxFormatted() {
      return this.boxID.replace(/\s+/g, '-')
    }
  }
}
```